# CSS: Opacity - Div doesn't show in IE7?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, filter, overlay, opacity

I created a overlay which i am using to show while doing ajax requests. In firefox it works great! But in IE7 i don't see the Div.

my div is simple its the first element after Body

```
<div id="overlay">
   &nbsp;
</div>
```

and my css is here

```
#overlay {
z-index:1000;
position:absolute;
top:0;
bottom:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
background:#000;
opacity:0.45;
-moz-opacity:0.45;
filter:alpha(opacity=45);
display:none;
}
```

I think it maybe something to do with the sizing as i placed some text in the div and i don't see it on IE7 but i do on firefox.

Does anyon know where its not working, i am at a bit of a loss :-)

I tried removing display:none and its the same and i also inserting   height:auto and still no joy.

I am using jquery to show and hide it liek so, but this isn't the problem as i removed Display:none and i don't see the div which should be over the top of the rest of the content

```
 $("#overlay").show();
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I tested in ie7 and works just like ie8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since your div is positioned in absolute you should specify an height (different than auto). This can be done declaring height:100% to `#overlay` , then also `html, body { height: 100% }` when you open the overlay and `html, body { height: auto }` when closing the overlay);

Another (better) way is to dinamically calculate the height of body elements via javascript (e.g. document.body.offsetHeight) and then assign to the #overlay as a height

`document.getElementById('overlay').style.height = document.body.offsetHeight + 'px';`

this would be written in you jQuery snippet as

```
$("#overlay").height($('body').height()).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following additional CSS:

```
#overlay {
    zoom: 1;
}
```